# How to get data from api response in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm using Angular 4, I've made a call to an api which returns an array of objects.

Then I tried to get specific data by referencing `res.name` but for some reason I get undefined so I tried `res[0]name` and `res['name']` which returns only the first name but I want all the names from the array.

Here is my array:

```
[{"name":"joey","surname":"jackson","email":"joey@gmail.com","phone":"0815342119"}, 
{"name":"Tim","surname":"Muller","email":"tim@gmail.com","phone":""}, 
{"name":"Kim","surname":"Van Dam","email":"kim@gmail.com","phone":""},
{"name":"Lyn","surname":"Davids","email":"lyn@gmail.com","phone":""}]
```

Comment: make your question a bit clear do you went to get the array of the name only ?

Comment: some of your values have null value so this may effect and show it as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `forEach` to iterate over all elements of an array:

```js
let res = [
{"name":"joey","surname":"jackson","email":"joey@gmail.com","phone":"0815342119"},{"name":"Tim","surname":"Muller","email":"tim@gmail.com","phone":""},{"name":"Kim","surname":"Van Dam","email":"kim@gmail.com","phone":""},{"name":"Lyn","surname":"Davids","email":"lyn@gmail.com","phone":"08343435"}
];

res.forEach( (el) => {
  console.log(el.name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dot operator when you are accessing property

it should be as,

**`res[0].name;`**

or

**`res[0]['name'];`**

Comment: that will return only the first name but i want all the names

Comment: so you have to loop or map over the items `res.map(item => item.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `let people = [your array of objects]`

In newer JS:

```
for (person of people) { 
    console.log(person.name) 
}
```